# How can I increase the database cache size?

Tags: synchronization, database

I'm running a full node on Windows and have plenty of RAM, is there a switch I can use to allocate a larger cache size? (Similar to -dbcache=X in Bitcoin/Litecoin core)

The Monero synchronization process was almost an order of magnitude faster (according to logs) when I put the database into a RAM drive (ImDisk) versus on the hard disk drive, but as the database grows in size this approach may not always be possible.

Answer (score 3):

No.

If you mean disk cache, assuming your OS isn't too dire, it should cache what's needed, and take it back when needed.

If you mean another type of cache, then the answer is still no, but with no extra comment :)